# unity change particle material without change the other particle system

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to change my particle material color without change the other particle system , every time I make a particle and I want to change his material (shader) or material color it applies to all my particle system and how can apply collision in it without box collider I tried to apply collision and it's not work

Comment: Hi, please edit your question to include the relevant source code. Thanks.

Comment: how to do that and any answer for the question there's no code in the answer and this question didn't include any code

Comment: Without any relevant code we can only guess what solutions might work if you provide us a code sample of what your doing,what you have tried, and what youve researched then we can better assist and give you an actual solution @SHOWCASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the material property of each renderer, then access the `material` property instead of the `sharedMaterial` property. The `material` property will create a new material instance.

ref doc:https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-sharedMaterial.html